# Reading text file and present data in python matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, defaultdict

I have tried to use python csv to read txt file then presented in graph using python matplotlib

simple of data in text file:

```
261 P 0.18 0 834 64627 0 768 0 320 834 64627 0 768 0 320 (radio 1.17% / 1.17% tx 0.00% / 0.00% listen 1.17% / 1.17%)
```

and this python script for reading the file but it does not work and no error message.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# for P lines
#0-> str,
#1 -> clock_time(),2-> P, 3->rimeaddr_node_addr.u8[0],rimeaddr_node_addr.u8[1], 4-> seqno,
#5 -> all_cpu,6-> all_lpm,7-> all_transmit,8-> all_listen,9-> all_idle_transmit,10-> all_idle_listen,
#11->cpu,12-> lpm,13-> transmit,14-> listen, 15 ->idle_transmit, 16 -> idle_listen, [RADIO STATISTICS...]


from collections import defaultdict
cpuOverTime =  defaultdict(list)

with open('loglistener.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] is 'P':
            cpuOverTime[row[3]].append(row[11])

for i in cpuOverTime:
    plt.plot(cpuOverTime[i])
plt.show()
##########
```

Comment: Did you mean `if row[1] is 'P':`?  Offsets are from 0 so the 2nd item is at offset 1.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, as is common with most programming languages, offsets start at 0 not 1.

From your sample data we can see that `P` is the 2nd space-delimited item in the row and therefore has index of 1:

```
Offset    0   | 1  | 2    | 3 | 4   | 5     | 6
Row       261 | P  | 0.18 | 0 | 834 | 64627 | 0
```

To fix the problem simply change the index to be 1:

```
with open('loglistener.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        if row[1] is 'P':
            cpuOverTime[row[3]].append(row[11])
```

I haven't checked but you likely have the same problem with `row[3]` and `row[11]`

Comment: now works well there was two values before P I should include                     00:02.396 ID:8  261 P 0.18 0 834 64627 0 768 0 320 834 64627 0 768 0 320 (radio 1.17% / 1.17% tx 0.00% / 0.00% listen 1.17% / 1.17%)